# How come some of my dashboards refresh automatically?

Tags: dashboard, refresh

When I access some of my dashboards, I notice they refresh automatically (spinners and "Getting your data" showing up) the moment the page starts loading.

For other dashboards the behavior is different, in that I need to click the "Refresh" button myself to get the same result.

When comparing the dashboards, I see no clear difference, nor do I find any documentation on this. Both the dashboards **have not been scheduled**, both are running as the logged in user, and both were last refreshed around 10 days ago (as I saw the 'as of' date right before the refresh happened).

I also noticed this 'auto-refresh' never happens for dashboards that have been refreshed recently (the last 24h or so)...

Is this documented somewhere? Why does this happen for some, but not all of my dashboards?

Comment: it may be because the underlying dashboard metadata has changed (new report sources, different component visualization)

Comment: That's not the case. Does anyone else have a similar behavior of auto-refresh from time to time?